# How to add current_item class to devise navigation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, navigation, devise

i want to add a current_item class to an active devise navigation, like login, registration etc. the menu consists also of some static pages, which are generated by the high_voltage gem. here i set it by the active page id and a class in the body tag.

how can i realize this for the devise navigation? any advice?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

fixed it myself with a helper in **application_helper.rb**

```
def set_title
  if controller_name == "registrations" && action_name == "new"
    "mitmachen"
  elsif controller_name == "sessions" && action_name == "new"
    "login"
  else
    params[:id]
  end
end
```